# iMacros in Firefox: Script stops when encountering 404 error

Tags: imacros

my script in iMacros (Firefox) stops after encountering a 404 error.
This happens despite

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
```

and

```
SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 1
```

and

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 3
```

Does anyone have an idea to prevent this script stopping problem for 404 pages?

Comment: forgot to say: if the pages exist, the script runs through them just fine...

Comment: hum...when I open another tab manually, the script continues to run... strange...

Comment: try to update imacros to 8.5.3 http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox

Comment: Bestmacros, you saved my ass. THANK YOU! Can I upvote your comment somehow?

Comment: you can add the info in your "forgot to say:" comment to the question by clicking on edit.